# "Constrained/Optimal" Topological Order to enhance/reduce the performance/memory usage of other algorithms

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, terminology, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

I currently work a lot with graphs, more specifically: directed acyclic graphs (DAGs). While working with DAGs, we are fortunate to use the topological sorting and then solve many different problems efficiently.

A usual use-case for me is to use a topological order with dynamic programming to retrieve interesting information, which would otherwise (outside the "graph-world") not be possible to calculate.

Multiple different topological orders can be retrieved in a graph. The entry in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Examples) very shortly illustrates this.

I know how to retrieve the topological order from a graph and wondered whether other topological orders could enhance/reduce the efficiency of algorithms applied afterwards.

Let's say: We want a topological order of a graph, which will be used in a dynamic programming approach. The ordering of the nodes needs to be selected specifically so that the memory usage of the dynamic programming approach is minimal.

To say it in other words: A topological order is needed, where the number of opened nodes is minimal. A node is open, if at least one predecessor was visited. It is closed(or set to not open) if it gets visited.

I plotted some of my basic ideas here (on a complicated and highly connected DAG):
[image: Opened Nodes by different topological orders]

In Blue: The Top. Order as in igraph.

In Yellow: A Top Order (as in [Khans algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn%27s_algorithm)) where i prioritized nodes with the lowest number of edges.

In Green: As in Yellow, prioritizing the nodes with the most edges.

In Red: Khans algorithm is used but nodes which have next nodes with most marked edges are prioritized.

All curves have less opened nodes at some point when iterating through the topological order, so this plot does not really show that one order is superior to the other.

---

These are only some thoughts i had and wanted to ask if this sketched problem can be optimized by other specific topological orders. In this specific case reduce the number of opened nodes more quickly (if possible?)..

Is there a term for such: "constrained/optimal" topological orders which i can use to search for?

Comment: Very cool question but probably off-topic for SO. Consider posting this question on the Math or CS stackexchange.

Comment: I think you are right. I posted this question also in CS [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141697/constrained-optimal-topological-order-to-enhance-reduce-the-performance-memory-u)